# How to get resolve Run time error 13 in my code for find and delete entire row in excel

Tags: excel, vba, string, mismatch

I am trying to write a VBA Script to delete a row which is selected from a dropdown list.
My code is

```
Sub delete_md_entry()
Dim LR As Long
Dim str As Range, rfnd As Range

'LR = Sheets("MASTER_DATA").Range("C2000").End(xlUp).Row
str = Sheets("MASTER_DATA").Range("I2").Value

    If Len(str) <> 0 Then
        Set rfnd = Selection.Find(str, After:=Range("C5"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        If Not rfnd Is Nothing Then
           yes = MsgBox("Do you want to delete" & rfnd.Value & " row?", vbYesNo, "Alert!")
            If yes = vbYes Then
                rfnd.EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
           MsgBox "NO ROW FOUND"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Kindly select a name!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it is not working and throw an error Run time error 13: Type mismatch.
However there is not with selection.
Where I made the mistake? Please help me to find out the error!

Comment: `str` is defined as a Range.  You either need to Set it to a Range, or define it as a String.

Comment: Also consider using a different variable name since that shadows the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Comment: I have tried both, str as Range and str as String.

Comment: `Set rfnd = Selection.Find(str, After:=Range("C5")` Does the selection include C5` ?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @CDP1802 no, the selection does not include C5

Comment: Thats the cause of your error see After parameter in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find)

Answer (score 0):

Find works on a Range and not on a single cell Selection.

You need to change

```
Set rfnd = Selection.Find(str, After:=Range("C5"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

To:

```
Set rfnd = Range("A2:C10").Find(str, After:=Range("C5"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Of course you need to change Range("A2:C10") above to whatever the range it is you are looking in.